# How can I merge 2 or more lucene indexes and avoid duplicated values in my final index?

Tags: java, lucene

How can I merge 2 or more lucene indexes and avoid duplicated values in my final index?

Today, I'm using this code to do merge among indexes:

```
        IndexWriterConfig iwc = new IndexWriterConfig(Version.LUCENE_36, new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_36));
        IndexWriter writer = new IndexWriter(getFSDirectory(INDEX_DIR), iwc);
        LogMergePolicy logMerge = new LogMergePolicy() {

            @Override
            protected long size(SegmentInfo arg0) throws IOException {
                return 0;
            }
        };
        logMerge.setMergeFactor(1000);
        iwc.setRAMBufferSizeMB(50);

        Directory indexes[] = new Directory[INDEXES_DIR.size()];

        for (int i = 0; i < INDEXES_DIR.size(); i++) {
            Directory d = FSDirectory.open(new File(INDEXES_DIR.get(i)).getAbsoluteFile());

            System.out.println("Adding: " + INDEXES_DIR.get(i));
            indexes[i] = d;
        }

        System.out.print("Merging added indexes...");
        writer.addIndexes(indexes);
        System.out.println("done");
```

Comment: when there are duplicates, which one should be kept?

Comment: anyone can be kept on final index

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe Lucene provides any nice easy way to do that, like `addIndexes`.

You will likely have to either:

Make another pass through the index to remove duplicates.  You could use [TermsEnum](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/index/TermsEnum.html) to get the `term()` and `docFreq()` of your id field in each document, to detect duplicates.  You could then get the DocIDs from a [`DocsEnum`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/index/DocsEnum.html), from a call to `TermsEnum.docs`.

Or, probably the saner way, perform the merge yourself, using [IndexWriter.updateDocument](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/index/IndexWriter.html#updateDocument%28org.apache.lucene.index.Term,%20java.lang.Iterable,%20org.apache.lucene.analysis.Analyzer%29) to prevent duplicates.